# How to fit text in line?

Tags: html, css

I want to bind text font-size with text length (in `<p>` with fixed width for example). Expected result is text fit in one line if it is only one word. If there are few words, it can be few lines.

I want to reduce font-size if word is too long for fixed-width line. For example, if "abc" fit in line I want to do nothing, if "abcdefg" doesn't fit in line I want to reduce text font-size

Comment: Please **[edit]** the question and give some examples. It sounds like you want to use a calculated font size, in such a way that the text "ABC" would occupy the same width as "ABCDEFG" would, and to do so the letters of ABC would need to be shown bigger. If not, then explain in more detail what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simply div setting your personal width, inside set your text, in css use

```
 display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

That way the text will respect your div width and brake line in your text when necessary

[flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)

Comment: It is not solution for my problem

Comment: @Oskar The solution was presented before you edited the question providing further explanation for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/), they now have responsive text incorporated.

You could also use media queries that change the text size when the screen size is smaller or larger:

```
/* If the screen size is 601px wide or more, set the font-size of div to 80px */
@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  div.example {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
}

/* If the screen size is 600px wide or less, set the font-size of <div> to 30px */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div.example {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

A final option would be to use the viewport width as the font size. Viewport is the browser window size. 1vw = 1% of viewport width. If the viewport is 50cm wide, 1vw is 0.5cm. Here's an example:

```
<h1 style="font-size:8vw;">Hello World</h1>
<p style="font-size:2vw;">Resize the browser window to see how the font size scales.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answer will satisfy your question.
The resizing part, which is the most important, is creditted to Jan Küster, with "Make text fit its parent size using JavaScript" article that you can find online.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].onkeyup = execute;

function execute() {
    let value = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    let words = value.split(" ");
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        html += ' <div class="text-container"><span class="text">' + words[i] + '</span></div>';
        document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0].innerHTML = html;
    }
    resizeText({
        elements: document.querySelectorAll('.text'),
        step: 0.25
    })
}
//
const isOverflown = ({
    clientWidth,
    clientHeight,
    scrollWidth,
    scrollHeight
}) => (scrollWidth > clientWidth) || (scrollHeight > clientHeight)

const resizeText = ({
    element,
    elements,
    minSize = 10,
    maxSize = 512,
    step = 1,
    unit = 'px'
}) => {
    (elements || [element]).forEach(el => {
        let i = minSize
        let overflow = false

        const parent = el.parentNode

        while (!overflow && i < maxSize) {
            el.style.fontSize = `${i}${unit}`
            overflow = isOverflown(parent)

            if (!overflow) i += step
        }

        // revert to last state where no overflow happened
        el.style.fontSize = `${i - step}${unit}`
    })
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #A33;
}

.parent {
  margin: 2%;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

.text-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<div class="parent">
</div>
```